# How to rebuild a NavigationView in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I'm rebuilding one of my apps in SwiftUI and wanted to add FaceID unlock. I found and used this article to add LocalAuthentication:
https://medium.com/swlh/app-lock-with-face-id-touch-id-in-swiftui-2-0-feef21e8eba7

While the code does handle the authentication part in the way that I need it to (although I'm showing the "locked view" as a sheet) it does result in one nasty bug.
When I dismiss the locked view (after successful authentication) my main view (which is a NavigationView) 'breaks' in the sense that the NavigationBar moves up into the statusbar. This behavior is also present in the code provided by the author of the article: https://github.com/JeevaTamil/AppLock

When I rotate my device the navigation 'restores' itself. So I was wondering if there is a way to force the NavigationView to rebuild itself, hopefully restoring the NavigationBar to the correct position.
I'm using Xcode 13.4.1 with an iOS 15.5 target, but the issue is also present in the iOS16 beta. Both on device and in the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can force rebuild any view by adding `.id` modifier dependent on some state. Any change of `id` to new value result in view rebuild.

Here is an example

```
@State private var force = false

// ...

NavigationView {
   Button("Rebuild") {
      force.toggle()    // << in any action/closure
   }
}
.id(force)   // << here !!
```

Of course it is not a silver-bullet and expensive operation, and in some cases might be not needed, but solution depends on real issue code.

Comment: Tried this, and it totally works! Now need to figure out how to set the force Bool from  the LockView. Tried linking it to the isAppUnLocked Bool but haven't gotten that to work just yet.

Comment: Figured out the problem. In the @main view the code uses scenePhase to apply a blurRadius. This caused the navigationView to break, als making it harder to force the rebuild as the view took a while to unblur and "break"

Comment: Try to keep in main/WindowScene only single ContentView() and all UI modifiers have inside that view, otherwise this affect window root view recreation, which might have undesired effects in general.